# How do you make money in Battlefield Hardline?

Tags: battlefield-hardline

I have been playing the Beta for some time now and I am starting to notice that I am earning cash to spend.   I can then use this money to purchase unlocks.

What are the different ways I can earn money?

I am pretty sure recovering money and depositing into your vault, earn you .001% of the total amount deposited, but are there any other methods to earning money?

Answer (score 2):

**Killing enemies** grants a variable amount of cash. I believe it depends on how you killed them - melee seems to reward more cash than a regular kill, same goes for marksman kills. While, from my experience, RPG kills grant less cash.

**Playing the objective** also grants an amount of cash, although I didn't have a chance to test it intensively yet, it seems to be a percentage of what you grab for bank heists.

I'm not sure for personal rewards (ribbons and such) yet, but I'll keep on testing and I'll come back here once I played more. **edit:** I don't own the official release so I cannot push my tests any further.

Answer (score 0):

Money in Hardline is the exact same thing as Score in BF4 and older.
In previouse BF games you unlocked Weapons, attachments, gadgets and so on due specific scores for classes, weaponclass and so on.

In Hardline this is different. You earn money for your actions and you can spend the money as you whish BUT you still have to reach specific score levels for the classes, before you can purchase something..

I got this info from playing the open beta, it may change.